# Problem in Computing the Energy in Energy Meter using ESP32

Tags: energy, esp32, code

So me and my groupmates are been working on with our thesis project about energy meter. In our project, the esp32 is the main board we are using. We also have voltage sensor (ZMPT101B) and current sensor (SCT013 100V:50mA) connected to our main board.

here is the link for the ZMPT101B... https://www.autobotic.com.my/ac-voltage-sensor-module-zmpt101b-single-phase

and here is the link for the SCT013... https://innovatorsguru.com/sct-013-000/

I am also using the Emon library from https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/emonlib/ to read the value thrown by the current and voltage sensor.

To get the power, i will multiply the current and voltage values.

Then to get the value of the energy i will be needing the time because Energy = Power x time. I saw formula online, it uses millis () function to get the time... but to be honest i dont know how millis works.

```
last_time = current_time;
current_time = millis();
Wh = Wh + power *(( current_time -last_time) /3600000.0) ;
```

The value of the energy will be send to the database, in our case our database is the firebase realtime database. Using this code...

```
Firebase.setDouble(firebaseData, path , KWh);
```

If the electricity cuts off , ESP32 will also be dead and will stop working. So we decided to add this line of codes...

```
Firebase.getInt(firebaseData, path);
totalEnergyDB = (firebaseData.intData());
preKWh = totalEnergyDB;
```

.... once the esp32 is turned on again, this code is used to get the data from the firebase... wherein the data got from the firebase will be used as a pre-kwh.

I used this lines of code to add the current readings from the pre-kwh.

```
KWh = (Wh/1000) + preKWh;
```

I set the calibration for the voltage and current sensor high so the changes will be easy to be seen.

My problem is that i was able to get the value from the database but it seems the energy formula is not working properly.

this is the result from the serial monitor... (171 KWH is the initial value from the database)
[image]

i wasn't able to show you the result of the power but it say in the lcd that it is around 3000W! But still Energy reading is not changing :(

Here is the complete code for our project...

```
#include "EmonLib.h"  
#define VOLT_CAL 52.5000
#define CURRENT_CAL 10.07
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 20, 4);

EnergyMonitor emon1;
int i;

// Wifi
#include <WiFi.h>
#include "FirebaseESP32.h"

#define FIREBASE_HOST "#!@#!@$!@a.firebaseio.com" 
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "RRw3u$!@%!@#%@#%$@%^#$^oI8LpQyVo0AWBC"
#define WIFI_SSID "WIFI"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "PASSWORD"

// Define Firebase Data object
FirebaseData firebaseData;

// Root Path
String path = "/USER INFO/jdc/totalEnergy";

float prev_voltage;
float prev_current;
float prev_power;
float prev_energy;

unsigned long last_time =0;
unsigned long current_time =0;
int Wh = 0;  
int preKWh;
int KWh;
int totalEnergyDB;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  initWifi();
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.begin(4, 20);
  
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(1,4);
  lcd.print("LOADING...");
  Serial.print("LOADING...");
  emon1.voltage(32, VOLT_CAL, 1.7);  // Voltage: input pin, calibration, phase_shift
  emon1.current(33, CURRENT_CAL); 
  for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
  emon1.calcVI(20,2000); 
  float currentDraw            = emon1.Irms;  
  float supplyVoltage          = emon1.Vrms; 
      
  }
delay(1); 
  Firebase.getInt(firebaseData, path);
  totalEnergyDB = (firebaseData.intData()); 
  preKWh = totalEnergyDB;
   
}

void loop() {
  emon1.calcVI(20,2000);
  float currentDraw     = emon1.Irms;             //extract Irms into Variable
  float supplyVoltage   = emon1.Vrms;
  float power = currentDraw * supplyVoltage;
  last_time = current_time;
  current_time = millis();
  Wh = Wh + power *(( current_time -last_time) /3600000.0) ; 
  KWh = (Wh/1000) + preKWh;

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("VOLTAGE: ");
  lcd.print(supplyVoltage);
  lcd.print(" V");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("CURRENT: ");
  lcd.print(currentDraw);
  lcd.print(" A");
  lcd.setCursor(0,2);
  lcd.print("POWER: ");
  lcd.print(power);
  lcd.print(" W");
  lcd.setCursor(0,3);
  lcd.print("ENERGY: ");
  lcd.print(KWh);
  lcd.print(" KWh");
  
  delay(100);  

    if (isnan(Wh)) {                       // if Wh is Not A Number
    Serial.println(F("Error reading Energy!"));
  }
  else {
    Serial.print(F("preKWh: "));
    Serial.print(preKWh);
    Serial.println(F("KWH"));
    Serial.print(F("Energy: "));
    Serial.print(KWh);
    Serial.println(F("KWH"));
    Firebase.setDouble(firebaseData, path , KWh);
    
    delay(100);
  }
    
    }
  

void initWifi(){
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("Connecting to Wi-Fi");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(300);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();

  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
  Firebase.reconnectWiFi(true);
  
  //Set database read timeout to 1 minute (max 15 minutes)
  Firebase.setReadTimeout(firebaseData, 1000 * 60);
  //tiny, small, medium, large and unlimited.
  //Size and its write timeout e.g. tiny (1s), small (10s), medium (30s) and large (60s).
  Firebase.setwriteSizeLimit(firebaseData, "tiny");
}
```

Comment: Information: you may be disappointed with the ZMPT101B so maybe leave a link to the actual data sheet?

Comment: no im not. thank you for reminding me, i definitely forgot to add that. thank you andy! :)

Comment: You do realize that at 3000W it takes 20 minutes to get 1 kWh

Comment: **ZMPT101B Output Signal: Analog 0-5V** - you cannot use this device to compute power accurately. However, that isn't your question; I just thought I'd double check this for you in case it comes up as a problem later down the line. Energy meters would never convert applied voltage to a DC value then multiply by current.

Comment: its been turned on for an hour so... :(

Comment: andy do you have any recommendation on what is the better voltage sensor to use in energy meter?

Comment: Ah, you need to recognize why it's a poor choice first and that delves into the math of single phase power calculations. Have you heard of power factor? If you want to trigger the site to tell me you have left a comment put `@andyaka` at the start of your message.

Comment: @Andyaka yes i have andy. though really my main problem is the coding :(

Comment: Probably off-topic for an electrical engineering site.